# Response on targeted attacks against an individual

Tags: attacks, incident-response, identity-theft

I'm now an aim for a targeted attack. Someone tries to gather information about me and tries to get access to my accounts. Some time before he/they've managed to succeed (got all the info from my email and restored passwords to accounts through it, but I don't know how they got the access to my email because the password remained the same and it has not been used anywhere else). Of course, the security log showed that they have been using Tor.

I regulally get emails that someone was trying to restore a password for one of the services I was signed up.

Now I've found a strange behavior on one of the services I'm signed up. It seems they have managed to get access again. Also I got a message from Facebook that someone was trying to enter my account. This means they know my email address and now they know my name (FB used to be disclosing it if you try password recovery or fail to sign in several times).

How to deal with this threat?

Answer (score 1):

Format your hard-drive, reinstall your OS of choice and then reset all your passwords online.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a local computer attack so formatting the drive won't help.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I agree, formatting the hard drive is what you would do if you're scared and naive, not after determining that's the only option.  Better to suggest they scan for viruses and malware, and turn on any 2 factor authentication.  Email doesn't really count, but it is better than nothing.